eclipse 2024-03: @param ... can not be resolved as a type
I installed Eclipse 2024-03 with Java and pdt extenstion. I imported a project and got many errors.


But Eclipse marks errors in documentation tags as you see in the picture.
Can somebody help to disable error tagging in doc-parts?

I updated the post. It is wrong on all comments as you see in picture 2

Are those messages also in the Problems View? What "Type" are they? Does it act differenty if your parameter name doesn't begin with a '$'? If this isn't about PHP code, why the PHP and PDT tags?

Yes the error is in the problem view too. It we be shown as Type "PHP Problem"

If i remove the @ in front of param the error will not shown.

If i remove $ it will not shown anymore. So: "* @param property"  works great. But i dont like to change all comments.
